If I understand the math better will I understand the physics better?
It is my understanding that physics is taught and understood fundamentally through the language of maths. Meaning, if you don't have a good grasp/ are fluent in the particular mathematics being used in a physics course, it's harder to reach a good physics understanding. Can anyone verify if this is true ? I ask because I just finished my degree in physics but I just come out of it with the feeling that I've never really grasped physics in a satisfying way and my conclusion is always that it's because I was never 100% comfortable with the maths. I just want to know that if I spent time really getting good at the maths first before applying it to physics would I get better at physics or is it just that really my brain doesn't click with physics and it doesn't matter how well I understand the maths? I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me, thanks.

If I understand the math better will I understand the physics better? Opinion-based questions are off-topic here. Please edit your question so that it has an objective answer. You know how your brain works better than any of us do.

I guess understanding (theoretical) physics requires a decent amount of maths. But the maths alone do not give you physical understanding. Sometimes the problems are not in the maths.

Math competency is necessary but not sufficient for understanding physics.

I found learning math by directly studying math to be too try to be interesting. I learned a lot of math by studying physics problems because the physics motivated me to dig through the math (as well as giving me a physical picture with which to understand the math). I'm not saying that will or won't work for you, I'm just saying that you should be wary of anyone telling you the best way to learn something. You should follow your own nose of what you find interesting and use techniques you find work well for you.

In my experience, I learned some topics much better when I taught them.  It's a little bit of a cliche, but the way to really learn something well is to have to teach it.
